# InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My current rails application has been built on ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3. I am doing bundle install one of the rails engines and I am received following error

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.8.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

How I can get rid of this issue without updating ruby version.

Comment: the nokogiri is the dependent gem

Comment: You have to find the gem that's requiring Nokogiri 1.8.2 and use a version that is compatible with your (ancient) version of Ruby.

Comment: It's really difficult to figure out from where it came. is there any way to figure out this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to install the compatible version of nokogiri with ruby version 1.9.3

`gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.8.1'` in your Gemfile.

But note, that Ruby versions below 2.1 are no longer maintained and no longer supported by nokogiri.

hope it will help you out

Comment: The OP isn't directly including Nokogiri; it's a dependency of something else he/she is pulling in.

Comment: nokogiri is the dependency of something and not sure what level is it. is there any way to find where it came? Due to some reason if ruby version is not upgraded then how we can resolve this type of issues.

Comment: as of now to debug this issue, if you are using git or svn, then you can check the version of nokogiri in a gemlock file on the previous commits. which will confirm that whether the version of nokogiri is changed or not.
To make sure this type of issues could not come in future you have to mention the version of every gem in gem file, which will not update the version of any gem while bundle install.